# inotify - what is the best way to go about it?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, nfs, inotify

I have inotify on my linux server. I looked up a whole lot of posting online on how to use inotify and found a sample c code that watches a directory for file create/delete. It worked fine on both local directory and nfs direcory(which is what i  really need)

Now looking at opitons on how to make this a always running process i see there are the below options at least from what i understand

1. I guess try to run this c code with a wait and never close it?
2. incrond - which apparently is a daemon process. I dont seem to have it on my linux server i have rhel5 so i guess i need to install it. Not very clear on how the incrond would work.
3. inotify-tools - this sounds the easiest as it says i can just use commands in a shell script

I also have questions like what happens when the nfs mount is removed, server shuts down etc., would inotify know to pick up from where it left?!

I know this is a lot of questions but any pointers would help me a great deal. Thanks in advance. Meanwhile i will continue playing with the sameple c code.

Comment: Why do you want to use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)? What for? What is the actual use case? Please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) works *reliably* with network file systems (either NFS or CIFS).

It could work (on the local host) if the local host is modifying/writing some NFS mounted system.

It won't work (on the local host) if some remote client is modifying/writing some NFS mounted system (mounted by the local host).

Because the NFS protocol (at least those that I know, pre NFS4) is an RPC protocol, and there is no way for the remote NFS server (mounting that NFS system) to signal to distant clients that something is happenning.

Comment: you are right. It doesnt work when i touch a file on the nfs server. I have a reuqirement where i need to listen on a directory and whenever a new file comes i need a shell script executed that will take the name of the file and generate a reference message and send it an application whihc will then pick up the file and process it. All these directories are NFS. If inotify doesnt work, what else can i use?

Comment: Nothing would work reliably, unless it runs on the NFS server itself. You might run on the client a `find` command on the mounted NFS system, but that could be slow (and won't be perfectly reliable)